# How can I add a new column with new values in it for all rows in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
Insert into employee (newsalary) 
values 
('21840'), ('15600'), ('26000'), 
('28847'), ('26000'), ('28600'), 
('32500'), ('39000'), ('32500'), 
('13026'), ('39000'), ('13026')
```

I have oldsalary with 30% increase, so I have to add new column with new salary values in new column name (newsalary) without changing any values with any other columns within same table.
how can I do that?

Comment: what datatype Newsalary is ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Update existing rows or add totally new rows? "Add new column" sounds like there are existing ones...?

Comment: No, you will need to do an `alter table ... add column ...` command to add the new column to the table and then do an `update` for each specific record to get the desired value for each row.

Comment: ok I have table already and i want to add new column with new value

Comment: and those values are 'int'

Comment: U mean something like this? http://codecorner.galanter.net/2010/01/05/t-sql-add-column-with-default-values-to-a-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add Column**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD newssalary datatype
```

Since it is a Salary Column, most probably you will need to do some mathematical calculation 
on it someday, so its best to use INT (Integer) datatype for this column.

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE table_name
SET newssalary  = 21840
WHERE PersonID = ???    --<--- Later Update Salary Column for all records
```

**UPDATE WIth 30%**

```
UPDATE table_name
SET newssalary  = (oldsalary * 1.30)
```

Comment: thank you. but in this case i have to add different values every time. can i do this together?

Comment: if you have a column OldSalary in your table all you need is to add another column, like shown in my very 1st statement and the update it using the last statement shown in my answer it will update the newSalary column with an increase of 30% for all the records in that table, using the value of OldSalary for that row.

Comment: @MuhammedAli You really dont need a second query to update. This can be done while adding the column. See my answer.

Comment: just another TIP when you inserting INT datatype you do not use single quotes around your values, Single Quotes are only used for string/Varchar/Char Datatypes

Comment: @AshishGupta this will set 30% increase as a default value for new salary column, so if you have a new employee in your company, the day company takes him on your code will give him a 30% wage raise,,, do you have any vacancies going on in your company pal ???? :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli Not really - when you add a row for a new employee, you can to supply a value - a default is default, you can always override it. The Also - question was to add a column for the existing rows.

Comment: @AshishGupta I havent really seen this AS syntax before is it does it work for sql server ???

Comment: @MuhammedAli - Yes It is for Sql server - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: @AshishGupta I was right then wasnt I ?? it is a computed column and every new record will get an increase of 30% :) any jobs going on in your company please :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli - Yes and No - Yes - when you don't specify the value for the new record. No - when you specify the value for the new record.

Comment: @AshishGupta If you dont mind can I add a bit of code in your answer then you'll know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the newsalary column computed from the existing salary column (30% increase in salary), do the following :-

```
ALTER TABLE data  
ADD newsalary
AS (salary + (salary * 0.3))
```

**Computed columns :**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: It should be something like this then ALTER TABLE #Temp
ADD RetailValue 
AS (salary *  1.30)